Find multidimensional Borel set consisting of one dimensional non-Borel set
Let be $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. I was wondering if it is possible to find a set $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $B=B_1\times B_2\times \dotsc B_n$ and show that there exists an $1\leq i\leq n$ with $B_i\notin \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?
I was tinkering around with the Vitali set (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), here denoted by $M$, which is not Lebesgue-measureable and hence $M\notin\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. This produces something like $(M\times \{0\}\times\{0\}\dotsc\times\{0\})$ which is indeed Lebesgue-measureable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) but I don't know if $(M\times \{0\}\times\{0\}\dotsc\times\{0\})\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Or maybe there is no "easy" counter-example?

$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra of $n$ copies $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, so $B_1\times B_2\times \dotsc B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if for all $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, we have  $B_i\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

@Ramiro what do you mean by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra of $n$ copies $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is indeed generated by $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times \dotsc\times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ but $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times \dotsc\times \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is certainly not true. How do you know that if $B_1\times B_2\times \dotsc B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then for all $1\leq i\leq n$ we have $B_i\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?


I wrote that "$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra of $n$ copies $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$". The product $\sigma$-algebra is NOT simply the cartesian product of the $\sigma$-algebra.  The product $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra GENERATED by the  cartesian product of the $\sigma$-algebra.
It is a well-know result that a set belongs to the product $\sigma$-algebra if and only if each section of the set belongs to the corresponding factor ($\sigma$-algebra).


For instance, see https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch5.pdf  In proposition 5.2 is what you are looking for. Using it, it is immediate that "$B_1\times B_2\times \dotsc B_n \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if and only if for all $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, we have  $B_i\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$".

@Ramiro I was a bit confused by the notation but you reference made it clear and answers my question :)
